# File on Google Drive doesn't appear in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm learning to use OpenCV on Colab to deal with object tracking in videos.

I have a sample .mp4 video called low den.mp4 that I uploaded "indirectly" to my own gdrive. So that I can mount it by:

```
import cv2
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then I can run the cell successfully by

```
path = "/gdrive/My Drive/low den.mp4"
```

But when I call

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
if not video.isOpened():
  print('Error while loading the video!')
  sys.exit()
```

Colab tells me this:

```
Error while loading the video!
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

I tried the "direct" method mentioned elsewhere:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Video upload alright. Then if I call

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(uploaded)
if not video.isOpened():
  print('Error while loading the video!')
  sys.exit()
```

Colab tells me this:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-39-b5c3939fe4ac> in <module>
----> 1 video = cv2.VideoCapture(uploaded)
      2 if not video.isOpened():
      3   print('Error while loading the video!')
      4   sys.exit()

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 
'VideoCapture'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'
>  - VideoCapture() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)
>  - Argument 'index' is required to be an integer
>  - VideoCapture() missing required argument 'apiPreference' (pos 2)
```

I need some help on understanding what went wrong in the "indirect" vs "direct" methods. And for the "direct" dialogue upload, how do I convert the uploaded video object to a file path and use it for other cv functions?

Thank you

Comment: what's the value of `type(uploaded)`? use `os.path.exists(some_path)` to test its existence.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz hi, the type(uploaded) is a dictionary as expected. As for the os.path.exists(), which path shall I put in? After uploading the video to Colab, I actually dont know its file path...

Comment: Actually, you inspired me to check the "indirect" method where I upload the video to my gdrive and mount gdrive... if I supply the path ("/gdrive/My Drive/low den.mp4") into the os.path.exists(path), it returned false. I'm so confused, as I know the video is there on the gdrive

Comment: if that says `False`, it's not actually there in colab. make sure you understand how to mount your gdrive files in Colab and where they are mounted.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I finally figured it out, thank you! The reason is the path indeed, instead of "/gdrive/My Drive/low den.mp4", I need to put it as "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/low den.mp4"